# How do I create Java Gradle Applications with different resources

Tags: java, gradle

I know this should be pretty simple, but there's obviously something that I'm just not getting.

I have a gradle application setup in the following in build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

application {
    mainClass = 'com.my.Main'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'other project 1'
    implementation 'other project 2'
}
```

The source is set up

```
src/
  main/
    java/
    resources/
```

I want to have a different distribution (for local development) that has different files for the resources directory, but for this 'dev' distribution, I want to keep the mainClass and the dependencies from the main distribution.

If I add a 'dev' distribution, I can package up files from the src/dev/... directory, but I don't have the application dependencies.

```
distributions {
    dev {
        contents {
            // something here to add the compiled java and dependencies from main
            // but not the resources?
        }
    }
    main {

    }
}
```

Also, gradle only seems to have one 'run' task that runs the main distribution. Is it possible to define a run for the dev distribution?

Comment: `contents` is a [CopySpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html), so you can copy wherever you want. What’s the problem you’re facing, you don’t know how to copy files?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, I'm not sure how to write the CopySpec so that the dev distribution gets the src and dependencies of the underlying of the application. 

If I just add the main/java, won't I just end up with the java files copied directly?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html

Comment: I've read that, and it doesn't help me with getting dependencies or compiled jars, at least I can see how. 

Could you possibly give me an example of how it might work in the case I've outlined in my question?

Comment: There no need to copy anything; I find this approach highly questionable ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler You, of course, have a right to your own opinion. Doesn't mean that's the only way, or the best way, to do things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a [`SourceSet`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) called `dev`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {

    }
    dev {
        resources {
            exclude ...
        }
    }
}
```

And also the corresponding directory (that's not even required, when only excluding files):

```
mkdir -p ./modulename/src/dev/resources
```

Comment: That allows me to define an entirely new source set, but not one that includes the main jar and only excludes a couple of resources, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Dunderklumpen You should have read the linked documentation ...which also explains that. Generally speaking, the default values of any source-set will always be source-set `main` - any other source-set will just override these values (these are being merged automatically).

Comment: Maybe I'm still misunderstanding, because when I add the dev sourceSet (with just excludes) gradle reports NO-SOURCE for the installDevDistributionTask

Comment: You can ignore that warning, while the task has no sources to compile. Commonly, it's called `debug` and not `dev` (this can also be combined with the `buildTypes` config)  ...also see: [Managing resources](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_resources).